# What effects can protect from enervation?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

I am playing a character in the Wrath of the Righteous Adventure Path and I want to specialize on the *[enervation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/enervation)* spell in particular. Therefore I took Mythic Enervation and Spell Perfection: Enervation.

What spells that protect targets from the spell effect (the level drain) are out there that I may have to cope with? I am aware of *[death ward](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/death-ward)*, but is there anything else?

Comment: Are yourself, an undead? Or plan to become one?

Comment: no, why are you asking?

Comment: There are quite a few effects that make you resist or become immune to abilities used by undead creatures. If you became one, the list of things that could be used against enervation would go up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On top of [Death Ward](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/death-ward), [Spell Immunity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/spell-immunity) (and it's variations) can make a target completely immune to the effects of *Enervation*. Note that it only affects 4th level spells and lower only (8th and lower for the greater version). So it should be available as soon as *Enervation*, but it's not available for arcane casters.

A [Black Soul Shard](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/a-b/black-soul-shard) can absorb a single negative level.

And a creature with [Negative Energy Affinity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/universal-monster-rules#TOC-Negative-Energy-Affinity-Ex-1) will be healed by *Enervation* as if it were an undead creature. An [Umbral Dragon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/dragons/dragon/-primal-umbral) is completely immune to *Enervation*. [Vemleks](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/outsiders/demon/demon-vermlek) are a low CR (3) demons that is also immune to it's effects. A 4th level [Agent of the Grav](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/agent-of-the-grave)e can obtain *Negative Level Affinity aswell.

A [Damphir](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-dhampir) character will also behave differently against Enervation. They will suffer no penalties from it, and will only die if they have enough negative levels as their HD, after the spell's duration is over, all negative levels are lost.

However, remember that the [Thanatopic Spell Metamagic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/metamagic-feats/thanatopic-spell-metamagic) could allow you to cast Enervation on targets that are resistant/immune to it.

Comment: “Also, don't forget that Enervation can also be targeted by Dispel Magic and have it's effects cancelled/removed,” is false. *Enervation* is an instantaneous effect and cannot be dispelled (there is no effect *to* dispel). The negative levels it imposes persist after the spell effect has ended, and *they* are harder to remove than just *dispel magic*.

Comment: @KRyan you are correct, i knew it had a duration, instead of being permanent levels, but the spell itself has no duration on it's effect block.